# Baikal Folder not Found

Tags: nginx, php

I tried to install baikal. Works perfectly, configuration, the website perfect. But when I try to get my books I get this error:

```
2016/12/24 10:21:40 [error] 6440#0: *7 "/var/www/mail/dav/html/dav.php/addressbooks/index.html" is not found (20: Not a directory), client: 46.223.1.8, server: dav.mailgermania.de, request: "GET /dav.php/addressbooks/ HTTP/1.1", host: "dav.mailgermania.de", referrer: "https://dav.mailgermania.de/dav.php"
```

This is my nginx config

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name dav.mailgermania.de
  server_tokens off;
  root /var/www/mail/dav/html;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443;
  listen [::]:443;
  server_name dav.mailgermania.de
  server_tokens off;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/mail/mail.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/mail/mail.key;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-  GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
  ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/mail/dhparams.pem;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
  ssl_session_timeout 30m;
  client_max_body_size 25m;
  root /var/www/mail/dav/html;
  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
  add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self';";
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
  add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

  rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /dav.php redirect;
  rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /dav.php redirect;

  charset utf-8;

  location ~ /(.ht|Core|Specific) {
    deny all;
    return 404;
  }

  location ~ .php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-mail-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 630;
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
  }
}
```

I do not know what this error means, maybe you could help me?

Thanks for help

**Update**
I changed my php block like this:

```
  location ~ ^(.+\.php)(.*)$ {
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param HTTPS on; 
fastcgi_read_timeout 630;
fastcgi_keep_conn on; 
}
```

Now it works. Thanks.

Comment: Instead updating your question with solution, you can either accept one existing answer or publish your own answer if you think additional details can be relevant. You can also accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a `try_files` block to your PHP handling location:

```
location ~ .php$ {
  try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.php;
  ...
}
```

This will give nginx a list of different things to try as it tries to locate the correct URI to run.

Comment: For what is the try handler